# How to pass Java Method within a Method's parameters or different solution

Tags: java, android, http

I am creating a mobile application using [[image]android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio). The purpose of this application is to copy the process used on an existing website (can't disclose the website for privacy reasons)

The website currently returns a JSON object when using a request with the parameters `usr` (username) and `pwd` (password). Example:

```
www.website.com/checkLogin.php?usr=username&pwd=password
```

The current working system is a function inside the main activity class of the application:

```
public void SimpleGetRequest(String url){

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // display the response for bug testing
                    Log.d("CREATION", "Response: " + response);

                    //ChangeText(response);

                    //Validate the JSON oBject that should be returned
                    if(ValidateLogin(response)){
                        // change the temp username and password in globals on static method
                        setUsernameAndPassword();

                        // change text to show success
                        ChangeText("Login Success");

                        // change ethe activity to the home page on the login screen
                        ChangeActivity();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ChangeText("Couldn't Connect to Server");
            Log.d("CREATION", "Request Failed");
        }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This method takes the url input and runs a simple request then returns the response in the `onResponse()` function it creates inside itself. This works fine for my purpose however I would like to use this method in other activities which would require me to copy and paste it into the other activities. Instead I want to create a static class that the activities to reference this method. however because the response resides in a callback function inside the method I cannot use the method to return anything.

The solution I thought possible is to pass a function from the activity using the `SimpleRequest()` method so when the callback function is called it sends the result back to the activity so it can be used instead of putting the functionality directly into the callback function.

Is it possible or this method flawed?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but it seems like you want to use either a lambda or method reference in place of the anonymous inner class. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, in essence i simply want to be able to set a pointer to a method for it to run so the response goes back to the activity that calls the request

Comment: This may help you out. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: That doesn't really help with my purpose. What i would like to do is move this method to its on static class, being a static class i can't use it to call a method in my non static class of the application, so what i would like to do is somehow pass a method in the SimpleRequest(final Method()) which i can then reference in the inner method onResponse() to send the response into

Comment: Is this possible/ is there another method similar that could work?

Comment: If you extract the method to the same class, you can reference it using `this::methodName`

Comment: I can't extract the method it is a abstract method as part of Response.Listener<String>()

Comment: I mean to move the method and use that in place of an anonymous class.`new StringRequest(GET, URL, this::onResponse, this::onError)`